# icono de warning en ecipse, no encuentro solucion

Tags: java, eclipse

En el IDE eclipse me salía en todos mis proyectos un ícono de warning , algo estaba mal , reinstalé eclipse y hice un proyecto nuevo, sigue saliendo el error, saben cual podría ser la solución? Gracias

anexo imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que dice la pestaña de errores?

Comment: Puede ser por que utilizas el paquete predeterminado o por que no utilizas un paquete fuente, eclipse da ese aviso por que según el no es muy "recomendable", creo que si utilizas otro paquete fuente o le cambias el nombre se irá el aviso.

Comment: Vete al menú 'Window -> Show view' y selecciona 'Problems'. Ahí te saldrán todos los Errors, Warnings (que es tu caso) e Infos que tienes. Una vez sepas cual es el problema podrás solucionarlo o volver a preguntar editando tu pregunta.